# Any way for Windows 10 Mobile to connect to VPN automatically like Windows Phone 8 can?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, settings, store, vpn

Windows Phone 8/8.1 has this great option in the VPN settings, quite appropriately just called "Connect automatically" which does exactly what it says.  The phone connects to the VPN I've checked "Connect automatically" for when I start it up, and doesn't send or receive any data unless it's connected to the VPN.

Windows 10 Mobile, sadly, is missing this simple but very cool and useful feature.

Has anyone come across any workarounds for this?  Something as simple as getting the **phone to connect to a VPN when it's powered on**?

I've looked in the Windows 10 Mobile Store but the apps are all for their own VPN services, not any generic VPN clients.

All I want to achieve is that the VPN profile that's set up in the Windows Phone OS VPN setting *get connected to at start-up, and stay connected to, which is already happening in Windows Phone 8.1*.

Comment: Would [Cisco AnyConnect](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/anyconnect/9wzdncrdj8lh?activetab=pivot:overviewtab#) be a good option to do what I want?  Does it have the simple feature I'm looking for?